# screen off on button click

Tags: android, android-button

i want to turn the screen of the device on button click,The code i used is as the follows

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button powerOff;
int amountOfTime =0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

powerOff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
powerOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        // Choice 1
        manager.goToSleep(amountOfTime);

        // Choice 2
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Your Tag");
        wl.acquire();
        wl.release();
    }
});
}
```

also given a permission

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Still it showing an exception that

```
   01-14 16:06:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9317): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   01-14 16:06:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9317): java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10079  nor current process has android.permission.DEVICE_POWER.
   01-14 16:06:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9317):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
   01-14 16:06:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9317):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
  01-14 16:06:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9317):   at android.os.IPowerManager$Stub$Proxy.goToSleep(IPowerManager.java:341)
  01-14 16:06:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(9317):   at android.os.PowerManager.goToSleep(PowerManager.java:464)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `DEVICE_POWER` permission.

EDIT:
Apparently, only system apps are allowed to use this permission, so you're practically stuck.

Comment: if i try to include this permission it showing error in manifest file,That permission only granted to system app

Comment: the permission only grated to system app

Comment: Yes, it seems that user applications cannot use this permission, no luck there.

Comment: I guess the reasoning behind it is that you could use it in a service and randomly turn off the user's screen any time.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I'm saying that the ***reason*** why only system applications can use it is because *otherwise*, if user apps ***were*** to use it in a service, they ***could*** randomly turn off the user's screen at any time, which enables malicious behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Add below permission to ur manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```